# Kaplan's Non-Linearity Test

Tags: r, time-series, nonlinear

I've been searching for an R package or function that applies the Kaplan non-linearity test to univariate time series but they are nowhere to be found. Such test has been widely applied in the analysis of financial time series such in the following [paper](https://www.mdpi.com/1099-4300/22/12/1435). I would really be grateful if someone can point me to such a package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This test is introduced in:

Kaplan, D. (1994), Exceptional Events as Evidence for Determinism, Physica D, 73, 38–48.

It is implemented as the function `determinism()` in the [package](https://rdrr.io/cran/fractal/man/determinism.html) `fractal`, which has been archived for over a year now. You can see the check results that caused the archivation [here](https://cran-archive.r-project.org/web/checks/2020/2020-06-09_check_results_fractal.html).

Comment: Hi @Grada Gukovic, Thank you very much for the answer! Do you know of any other package? I tried installing older versions of the package but I failed each time. It's really strange how such a test isn't easily found in R nor python.